# How do I paginate results from the Facebook SDK friends endpoint?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-friends

I'm using the Facebook SDK for JS to get a list of FB friends for a given FB user ID. Essentially, I make a request as follows:

```
FB.api(`/${fbUserId}/friends`, (response) => {
    if (response && response.data) {
        fbFriends = fbFriends.concat(response.data);
    }

    if (response && response.paging && response.paging.cursors && response.paging.cursors.after) {
        // Recurse through.
    }
});
```

I can get the first set of results, which contains 13 friends, and can also see that there are 200+ friends total, but the problem I'm having is when I try to recurse through and get all 200+ friends.

Specifically, I'm referencing the following two pages:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#cursors
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

Trying to put things together from those two pages, I thought that a request URL like the following would work:

```
const afterParam = response.paging.cursors.after ? `&after=${response.paging.cursors.after}` : '';

FB.api(`/${fbUserId}/friends${afterParam}`, (response) => {
...
```

But it doesn't return any results. I am console-logging `response.paging.cursors.after`, and I'm sure it's set appropriately from the first API call, but it's not returning any more friends. I always get back an empty array for `response.data`.

What am I doing wrong? Admittedly, the FB API docs seem a bit sparse, and I don't see anywhere where they specifically show how to go through pages of results for the friends API endpoint, but I'm obviously missing something. Thank you.

Comment: No that is how it suppose to work. You can only get friends that granted user_friends permission to the app. You get a count on how many users the user have in total. But you will only get the friends that granted user_friends permission to the app

Comment: Gotcha. So the 13 I'm getting back is the total number of friends that have allowed access? Makes sense. That said, how do I know if there are legitimately multiple pages of results or not? Thank you.

Comment: Cursor pagination is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#cursors

Comment: Yes, I referenced that page in my question, but I'm just now better understanding the following: next: The Graph API endpoint that will return the next page of data. **If not included, this is the last page of data.** Due to how pagination works with visibility and privacy, it is possible that a page may be empty but contain a next paging link. Stop paging when the next link no longer appears.